# apt-get update is running but still can't add repo with add-apt-repository in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, repository

I was trying to install Grub Customizer, so I entered

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

The output was

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I then entered (to trying fixing this)

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

I then run (to fix the previous error)

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

Lastly, I enter

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

I am out of ideas on how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The PPA is intended for Ubuntu and its derivatives, not for Kali. As the Grub Customizer documentation indicates, you should [build it from source](https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1397).

Answer (score 0):

To install grub Customizer run the following command:

```
apt-get install build-essential cmake libgtkmm-3.0-dev libssl-dev gettext libarchive-dev 
wget https://goo.gl/qQnUhK -O grub-customizer_4.0.6.tar.gz 
tar xfv grub-customi* 
cd grub-customi* 
cmake . && make -j3 
make install
```